# Difference footprints of part in Altium Designer

Tags: altium, component-selection

What is the numerical difference between footprints marked with "* _M", "* _N", "* _V" and "* _L"?

P.S. I was looking any information in google, but as a result nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think they stand for

N-nominal,
M-maximum,
L-least

Not sure about V though.

Also if you look closely, for example, at SMD0805's N, M and L variants, you will find that they increase in size, just by little.

About why are they used when there isn't much of a difference in their sizes, read this: 
https://blogs.mentor.com/tom-hausherr/blog/2011/01/28/pcb-design-perfection-starts-in-the-cad-library-part-12/

Comment: Actually, thanks for asking the question. 
I always thought N,M and L were normal, medium and large. :)

Comment: Also, "by eye" "V"-footprint does not many differ from "L"-footprint. It stands for "very least", I think.

P.S. Became we get smarter now. :)

Comment: If you found the answer useful, please +1

Comment: I noted the answer as useful and gave +1, but I can not see whether it was counted or not.

Comment: You need 10 reputation to upvote an answer I guess!!